# Filter out anything that isn't a number

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My code below works to pass the variable emails to the `GmailApp` as recipients of an email.  This filters out any row that isn't blank.  I have run into a new issue where it is encountering bad data.  Is there a way to have it filter out anything that isn't a number instead of blanks?

```
var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
//var contacts = originalSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
//var numRows = contacts.getLastRow();
//var emailTo = contacts.getRange(2, 1, numRows, 1).getValues();  

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const contacts = ss.getRange('A2:A17').getValues(); // 2D array
const filtered = contacts.filter ( function (row) {
                   return (row[0] != "");})

const emails = filtered.map(function (nameRow) { return nameRow[0] + "@gmail.com"; });
```

Comment: Give an example of what is "bad data" and what is "good data"?

Comment: anything that wouldn't result in a proper email address.  For my project bad data = anything that isn't a number.  Good data = anything that is a number

Comment: Please share the results of your research into how one can check if a string is a number or not using JavaScript. Your goal is to replace the boolean predicate used by `filter` with that new predicate

Answer (score 1):

Could you use something like,

```
const filtered = contacts.filter(function (row) {
  return !isNaN(row[0]);
});
```

`isNaN` will return true on all non-numbers not just `NaN` values.

---

(Google doesn't currently support arrow functions, should this change, or you need the solution in a different context, the following might work too)

```
const filtered = contacts.filter(row => !isNaN(row[0]));
```

Comment: Right-oh. I'll amend my answer. Thanks :)